# Are firebase hosted websites indexed by google?

Tags: firebase, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

I was wondering if firebase domains: `.web.app` and `.firebase.app` are indexed by Google.

I hosted my website at `myprojectname.web.app` but when searching after the name on google nothing comes up.

Do I have to do something to make it work? I'm not very familiar with SEO stuff.

Answer (score 6):

Sites on Firebase Hosting are not automatically indexed by Google search. If you want your web site to show up, you'll have to submit it yourself. For more on this, see the documentation on [asking Google to recrawl your URLs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/ask-google-to-recrawl).